# Need advice with getting info from database and displaying

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to figure out what is best and easy way without writing much code. So there is an Admin panel and I want many stuff to show from database info, like how many users, how many posts, etc.

Here is the controller:

```
public function userCount()
{
   $count = DB::select('select count(*) as total from users');
   return view('/admin', ['count' => $count[0]->total]);
}
```

Then here is the Route:

```
Route::get('/admin', [AdminController::class, 'userCount']);
```

And then in `admin.blade.php` where info is just printing:

```
{{$count}}
```

The question is if it there is a right way to make like this or there is better way?

Example I can create maybe 1 controller `InfoController` and get all info from FB, create them as functions and then print in `admin.blade.php`?

Should I be using for every function a new route?

Also if there are any fixes in code, maybe something should be deleted and no need, you can advise me. Thanks!

Comment: Laravel has aggregate methods, you can simply call `User::count()` too
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates

Comment: `public function userCount() { return view('/admin', ['count' => User::count()]); }`

Comment: @Hunman When I tried User::count() then Im getting error Class 'User' not found. I also included use App\Models\User; inside AdminController.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function userCount() { 
    return view('/admin', ['count' => User::count()]); 
}
```

Class 'User' not found, occurs when you enter the class name or name space incorrectly.

Comment: Do I still need to make this userCount in controller? I entered {{User::count()}} inside admin.blade.php and getting this error.

Comment: You should use User::count() in controller and then pass it to admin.blade.php.
You can alos {{ App\Models\User::count() }} in admin.blade.php but it's not standard wey.